# SSRS report dataset creation not showing my procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services

strong text[image]

Trying to add dataset to my report but cant find my procedure in the list
I added my query to a different proc to check and I cant see fields is there anything wrong with the query?

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[CV_RPT_ReciptSummary] 
    (@i_days int)
AS 
    SET FMTONLY ON
    SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    SELECT --COUNT(EN_PK) as total,
        DE_Comments, 
        EN_FirstName, EN_LastName, 
        ISNULL(DE_Offender_Paid, 0) AS DE_Offender_Paid,
        DE_Rest_Amt, OS_Type, DE_FK_CL, CL_Number 
    FROM
        CV_Debt_Offender 
    INNER JOIN
        CV_ENTITY ON DE_FK_Offender_EN = en_PK
    INNER JOIN
        CV_CLAIMS ON CL_PK = DE_FK_CL 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        CV_Offender_Status ON OS_PK = DE_FK_Offender_Status  
END
```

Comment: have you tried, closing and reopening the solution? Have you confirmed the proc actually exists? FYI: You can always add the dataset by hand (don't use the wizard)

Comment: yes I restarted the solution and even the machine.when i go to create a datasource its not in the list there too. Is there any other way?

Comment: What devleopment tools are you using, Visual Studio?

Comment: yes visual studio 2019. its a report in windows application

Comment: Insteasd of using a wizard, what happens if you right lcik on Datasets -> Add Dataset - Use a dataset embedded in my report -> select Data source -> select Stored Procedure as query type and then simply enter the name of your SP -> CV_RPT_ReciptSummary

Comment: right click and add datasource takes me to the wizard as above picture.

Comment: A DataSOURCE is just a connection to a server (in this case), if you want to get data from a storped proc you need to adding a DataSET. A dataset will need a datasource so normallt you would create a datasource to your SQL Server and then a dataset which would be a sql query, table, view or stored proc

Answer (score 1):

After trying lot of different ways, finally this is what worked for me.
ADD new item to solution create new dataset in solution and drag stored procedure from server explorer and then use this .xsd file to replace dataset in report and that did.
Still cant figure out why its not in the list to create a dataset directly from report.